# Identify process definition id for history cleanup (ttl)

Tags: spring-boot, bpmn, camunda

I need to set TTL using Java API.

```
 processEngine.getRepositoryService().updateProcessDefinitionHistoryTimeToLive(processDefinitionId, 5);
```

But how can i get processDefinitionId, if it generates every time using UUID?
For example:

first process execution - DeviceProvisioning:1:e97e77dd-adeb-11e9-9a46-ca154a03850c

Second execution - DeviceProvisioning:1:0ea37b55-aded-11e9-9e25-ca154a03850c

Answer (score 1):

Use the processDefinitionQuery (Limited by processDefinitionKey) and then loop over all definitions found if you want to set Tal for all deployments.